# How do I insert the latest TFS changeset number into an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, tfsbuild

When we were using SVN, we'd always print at the footer of our pages: "Revision XXXX". I've been looking, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing with TFS. Can anyone offer some pointers?

In case this matters: we're using ASP.NET MVC. I'm guessing it doesn't matter, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a MsBuild task that searches for a particular string and replaces with the appropriate value (not necessarily the revision number).

The task runs as part of our build templates and puts the revision number in all the files that have the token present.

Comment: @K.R.R how do you intend to display the number, will it be hard coded into each page or will you pull it from another place?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the default version system for assemblies to track revisions number without adding anything in TFS.

If you use the `Major.Minor.*` format in your `AssemblyInfo`'s `AssemblyVersion` attribute (e.g. `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`) it will generate a version according to the following format:

```
Major.Minor.Build.Revision
```

where

- Major = Your value
- Minor = Your value
- Build = Number of days since
  2000/01/01
- Revision = (Number of seconds since midnight on the day
  specified in Build) / 2

This will give you an always increasing number which gives you precise information on build date and time.

To use these values in your code, you can simply recover the version using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`.

Answer (score 1):

You can update version number of projects in `AssemblyInfo.cs` using assembly versioning tools/techniques like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221181553/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jimlamb/archive/2009/11/18/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx). Version number of an assembly can be updated based on TFS changeset number. Version number then can be displayed in application.

Answer (score 0):

At least when it was released, TFS didn't allow symbol replacement in files which is what I think you're after.  I'm not sure if that has changed in more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Changeset != Version

That being said, you can add a setting in web.config that holds the version number, and display that on the page. The version number can be updated as part of the build process, but it will not correlate to a changeset.

I should probably add that this can become a circular problem. If you get the latest changeset number for a project, then add that to the config (as named above), then checkin, you are no longer displaying the latest changeset. Adding 1 to the latest changeset is not a guarantee either, because something can be checked in while you are updating the files.